React Dropdown Issue: All Dropdowns Open Simultaneously When Clicking Any Dropdown Button or External Elements
I am building a reusable dropdown component in React that can be toggled both by clicking its button and by clicking on external elements (watchElements). The dropdown works fine individually, but when I render multiple instances of the dropdown, clicking any button or external element toggles all dropdowns at once.
I want each dropdown instance to manage its own state independently so that clicking on a specific button or external element toggles only that specific dropdown.
Here is the current code for the Dropdown component:
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

mport Button from "./Button";
import { RiArrowDownCircleFill } from "@remixicon/react";
import { constants } from "../constants";

const Dropdown = ({
  content,
  img = {
    url: "",
    alt: ""
  },
  img_classes = "",
  btn_classes = "",
  className = "text-center",
  content_wrapper_classes = "",
  btn_child = (
    <RiArrowDownCircleFill
      size={constants.static_sytles.icon_size_sm}
      className="text-white animate-bounce"
    />
  ),
  children,
  watchElements = []
}) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false); 
  const dropdownRef = useRef(null);

  const toggleDropdown = (event) => {
    // console.log(dropdownRef.current)
    console.log('here is the event', event.target)
    console.log(dropdownRef.current.contains(event.target))
    if (dropdownRef.current && dropdownRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
      setIsOpen((prev) => !prev);
    }
  };

  const closeDropdown = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
    if (
      dropdownRef.current &&
      !dropdownRef.current.contains(event.target) &&
      !watchElements.some(
        (el) => el && el.contains && el.contains(event.target)
      )
    ) {
      closeDropdown();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);

    if (watchElements.length) {
      watchElements.forEach((watchElement) => {
        if (watchElement) {
          watchElement.addEventListener("click", toggleDropdown);
        }
      });
    }

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);

      if (watchElements.length) {
        watchElements.forEach((watchElement) => {
          if (watchElement) {
            watchElement.removeEventListener("click", toggleDropdown);
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }, [watchElements]);

  return (
    <div className={`${className}`}>
      <Button
        className={`${btn_classes} mt-3 flex items-center justify-center w-full`}
        // onClick={toggleDropdown}
        isDefault={false}
      >
        {btn_child}
      </Button>

      {/* Dropdown Menu */}
      <div
       ref={dropdownRef}
        className={` ${content_wrapper_classes} right-0 top-full w-full bg-white ring-opacity-5 overflow-hidden transition-all duration-700 ease-in-out ${
          isOpen  ?  "max-h-screen animate-flip-down" : "max-h-0"
        }`}
      >
        {img.url && (
          <img className={`${img_classes}`} src={img.url} alt={img.alt} />
        )}
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dropdown;

Usage:
const containerRefs= React.useRef([]);

{constants.home_services.map((service, index) => (
  <div
    className="w-full relative"
    key={index}
    ref={(el) => (containerRefs.current[index] = el)}
  >
    <div
      className={`${constants.static_sytles.bg_color_secondary_heavy} shadow-sm ${constants.static_sytles.shadow_secondary_heavy} px-4 py-2 rounded-md gap-y-2 border-2 border-[#9b9fab] flex justify-between items-center cursor-pointer`}
    >
      <h2 className="text-xl md:text-2xl font-light">{service.name}</h2>
      <img
        className="h-14 w-20 rounded-sm"
        src={service.ImgUrl}
        alt={service.name}
      />
    </div>
    <Dropdown
      watchElements={containerRefs.current}
      img={{ url: service.ImgUrl, alt: service.name }}
      btn_classes=""
      className=""
      img_classes="w-full rounded-sm h-80"
      content_wrapper_classes="rounded-lg"
      btn_child={
        <RiArrowDropDownFill
          className={`${constants.static_sytles.icon_color_secondary} ${constants.static_sytles.icon_size_sm}`}
        />
      }
    >
      <p className="mt-2 p-3">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Accusantium,
        quisquam voluptatem odio sapiente mollitia, autem nostrum quod vitae
        aliquam quam non exercitationem consequatur architecto distinctio
        numquam rerum odit. Nemo, eaque!
      </p>
    </Dropdown>
  </div>
))}

I have tried to use the watchElements prop to hold the references of external elements to attach eventListners and use them to toggle dropdowns

In your usage example, you're passing the entire containerRefs.current array to each dropdown's watchElements prop. Is your intention to have each dropdown watch only its corresponding container, or should each dropdown watch all containers?

Thanks for you response, i want each dropdown to watch its corresponding container can you help me further?

The main issues in the current code are:

Each dropdown is receiving all container refs instead of just its
own
The event handling logic needs to be specific to each dropdown
instance

Here are the necessary changes:
// ... imports remain the same

const Dropdown = ({
  content,
  img = {
    url: "",
    alt: ""
  },
  img_classes = "",
  btn_classes = "",
  className = "text-center",
  content_wrapper_classes = "",
  btn_child,
  children,
  watchElements = [] // This will now receive a single element instead of an array
}) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const dropdownRef = useRef(null);

  const toggleDropdown = (event) => {
    setIsOpen((prev) => !prev);
  };

  const closeDropdown = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
    if (
      dropdownRef.current &&
      !dropdownRef.current.contains(event.target) &&
      !(watchElements && watchElements.contains && watchElements.contains(event.target))
    ) {
      closeDropdown();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);

    // Add click listener to the single watch element
    if (watchElements) {
      watchElements.addEventListener("click", toggleDropdown);
    }

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
      
      if (watchElements) {
        watchElements.removeEventListener("click", toggleDropdown);
      }
    };
  }, [watchElements]);

  // ... rest of the component remains the same
};

export default Dropdown;
And here's how to modify the usage:
{constants.home_services.map((service, index) => (
  <div
    className="w-full relative"
    key={index}
    ref={(el) => (containerRefs.current[index] = el)}
  >
    <div
      className={`${constants.static_sytles.bg_color_secondary_heavy} shadow-sm ${constants.static_sytles.shadow_secondary_heavy} px-4 py-2 rounded-md gap-y-2 border-2 border-[#9b9fab] flex justify-between items-center cursor-pointer`}
    >
      <h2 className="text-xl md:text-2xl font-light">{service.name}</h2>
      <img
        className="h-14 w-20 rounded-sm"
        src={service.ImgUrl}
        alt={service.name}
      />
    </div>
    <Dropdown
      watchElements={containerRefs.current[index]} {/* Pass only the corresponding container ref */}
      img={{ url: service.ImgUrl, alt: service.name }}
      btn_classes=""
      className=""
      img_classes="w-full rounded-sm h-80"
      content_wrapper_classes="rounded-lg"
      btn_child={
        <RiArrowDropDownFill
          className={`${constants.static_sytles.icon_color_secondary} ${constants.static_sytles.icon_size_sm}`}
        />
      }
    >
      <p className="mt-2 p-3">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Accusantium,
        quisquam voluptatem odio sapiente mollitia, autem nostrum quod vitae
        aliquam quam non exercitationem consequatur architecto distinctio
        numquam rerum odit. Nemo, eaque!
      </p>
    </Dropdown>
  </div>
))}


Thanks for your help. However, can you please help me with another question in the same context regarding useRef? In the above code, I am using the useRef hook to store the refs of external elements, but due to the behavior of the useRef hook, on the initial render, containerRefs.current is undefined, which causes the dropdowns not to work. Can you have a look at this again? Thanks in advance!
